# Creating new data table based on ifelse on old data table

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, subset

I'm trying to subset my data table using an ifelse statement, but I am not getting the result that I was looking for.

My initial data table looks like this:

```
head(Data_copy, n = 18)

    Company       Date       DOW variable value Year Month End_of_Month
 1:   ASXRI 1991-09-06    Friday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
 2:   ASXRI 1991-09-09    Monday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
 3:   ASXRI 1991-09-10   Tuesday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
 4:   ASXRI 1991-09-11 Wednesday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
 5:   ASXRI 1991-09-12  Thursday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
 6:   ASXRI 1991-09-13    Friday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
 7:   ASXRI 1991-09-16    Monday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
 8:   ASXRI 1991-09-17   Tuesday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
 9:   ASXRI 1991-09-18 Wednesday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
10:   ASXRI 1991-09-19  Thursday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
11:   ASXRI 1991-09-20    Friday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
12:   ASXRI 1991-09-23    Monday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
13:   ASXRI 1991-09-24   Tuesday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
14:   ASXRI 1991-09-25 Wednesday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
15:   ASXRI 1991-09-26  Thursday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
16:   ASXRI 1991-09-27    Friday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            0
17:   ASXRI 1991-09-30    Monday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            1
18:   ASXRI 1991-10-01   Tuesday       RI    NA 1991   Oct            0
```

This is 18 rows out of 250,000.

What i want is to split this data table based on an ifelse function as follows:

```
Data1 <- ifelse("Weekly" == "Weekly", Data_copy[End_of_Month ==1,], Data_copy)
```

*The "Weekly" == "Weekly" bit is going to be used in a function later.

I want Data1 to be a new data table which only contains the rows where End_of_Month ==1.

When i run the above code, I find that I get a **list** of the Company names and that is it.

I'll show you what the output looks like:

```
Data1[[1]]
    [1] "ASXRI" "ASXRI" "ASXRI" "ASXRI" "ASXRI" "ASXRI" "ASXRI" "ASXRI" "ASXRI" "ASXRI" "ASXRI"
```

Now if I scroll further down I get:

```
[1387] "AANRI" "AANRI" "AANRI" "AANRI" "AANRI" "AANRI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI"
 [1398] "APARI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI" "APARI"
```

Each of these entries is just one of the Company names.

I get my desired result if I do:

```
Data2 <- Data_copy[End_of_Month == 1, ]

Company       Date      DOW variable value Year Month End_of_Month
1:   ASXRI 1991-09-30   Monday       RI    NA 1991   Sep            1
2:   ASXRI 1991-10-31 Thursday       RI    NA 1991   Oct            1
3:   ASXRI 1991-11-29   Friday       RI    NA 1991   Nov            1
4:   ASXRI 1991-12-31  Tuesday       RI    NA 1991   Dec            1
5:   ASXRI 1992-01-31   Friday       RI    NA 1992   Jan            1
6:   ASXRI 1992-02-28   Friday       RI    NA 1992   Feb            1
```

Essentially I'd like to replicate Data2, but using an ifelse statement.

Here's the first 100 rows:

```
dput(head(Data_copy, n = 100))
structure(list(Company = c("ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", 
"ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI", "ASXRI"), Date = structure(c(7918, 
7921, 7922, 7923, 7924, 7925, 7928, 7929, 7930, 7931, 7932, 7935, 
7936, 7937, 7938, 7939, 7942, 7943, 7944, 7945, 7946, 7949, 7950, 
7951, 7952, 7953, 7956, 7957, 7958, 7959, 7960, 7963, 7964, 7965, 
7966, 7967, 7970, 7971, 7972, 7973, 7974, 7977, 7978, 7979, 7980, 
7981, 7984, 7985, 7986, 7987, 7988, 7991, 7992, 7993, 7994, 7995, 
7998, 7999, 8000, 8001, 8002, 8005, 8006, 8007, 8008, 8009, 8012, 
8013, 8014, 8015, 8016, 8019, 8020, 8021, 8022, 8023, 8026, 8027, 
8028, 8029, 8030, 8033, 8034, 8035, 8036, 8037, 8040, 8041, 8042, 
8043, 8044, 8047, 8048, 8049, 8050, 8051, 8054, 8055, 8056, 8057
), class = "Date"), DOW = c("Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"
), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("RI", 
"VO", "MV", "TD", "ND"), class = "factor"), value = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), Year = c("1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", 
"1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", 
"1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", 
"1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", 
"1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", 
"1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", 
"1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", 
"1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", 
"1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", 
"1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", 
"1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1992", "1992", "1992", 
"1992", "1992", "1992", "1992", "1992", "1992", "1992", "1992", 
"1992", "1992", "1992", "1992", "1992", "1992"), Month = c("Sep", 
"Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", 
"Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Oct", "Oct", 
"Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", 
"Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", 
"Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", 
"Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", 
"Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", 
"Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", 
"Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", 
"Dec", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", 
"Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan"
), End_of_Month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), .Names = c("Company", "Date", "DOW", "variable", "value", 
"Year", "Month", "End_of_Month"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -100L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001f0788>)
```

Comment: I'd like to replicate your initial data.table

Comment: @jangorecki I've added some data if you'd like to try.

Comment: Going out of your way to use `ifelse` is generally a bad idea. Despite the function's nice syntax, it has a large number of downsides and limitations, so I'd stick with the approach you have, `Data_copy[End_of_Month == 1]`. Maybe I'm missing something, since you didn't say why you want to use `ifelse` here.

Comment: I'd like to make a function where the inputs determine whether the data is on a monthly, weekly or daily frequency. 

For instance, the first chunk of my function looks like this:

`equal_weight <- function(Data, start, end, frequency){
  Data1 <- ifelse(frequency == "Weekly", Data[End_of_Month == 1, ], Data)`
return(Data1)}`

So in this block of code i'd enter, `equal_weight(Data_copy, Weekly)`
* My start and end args aren't used in this block

I'd like to be able to set the frequency argument  to Weekly/Monthly/Daily eventually.

Does that help?

Comment: ifelse is the wrong function for that. Use if and else or switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other users have noted that `ifelse` is inappropriate for your purposes. It may be useful to explain why. From `?ifelse`, `ifelse(test, yes, no)` returns a

> vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions
>        and ‘"class"’) as ‘test’ and data values from the values of ‘yes’
>        or ‘no’

In other words, if your `test` vector is length 1, `ifelse(...)` will return a vector of length 1.  For example,

```
> ifelse(TRUE, 1:3, 7:9)
[1] 1
> ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1:3, 7:9)
[1] 1 8
```

In your case,

```
ifelse("Weekly" == "Weekly", Data_copy[End_of_Month ==1,], Data_copy)
```

will return a vector of length one.  More precisely, since the test returns `TRUE`, `ifelse` will return the first element from your `yes` argument; since it is a dataframe (a type of list), `ifelse` returns the first element of the dataframe, which is the first column.  This is why you get a list of the company names.  If you really want to use the `ifelse` construction, try

```
ifelse("Weekly" == "Weekly", list(Data_copy[End_of_Month ==1,]), list(Data_copy))
```

although as others have said, you may be better off using `if {} else {}`.